# How to measure radio wave penetration and reflection through different mediums

Tags: rf, frequency-measurement, propagation, vna, spectroscopy

I would like to do a few experiments to test how different EM radiation frequencies (915 MHz to 5 GHz) interact with 3D print filament materials (like PLA, PolyCarbonate, TPU, etc...). Specifically I want to measure the signal strength of the reflected wave and penetrated wave by the medium. My setup would be something like the figure below:
[image]

I have a rectangular piece of material (12x12x0.2 inch), a source signal, and two receiving antennas. I don't know what components I would need to do this experiment and what would be the approach to get accurate measurements. Let's just say I want do the experiment for 915 MHz. I was thinking of getting a signal generator and a vector network analyzer. Even if I generate the signal on the transmitter, how would I know that receiver 2 is getting the reflected signal and not one directly from the transmitter? And Receiver 1 is getting the signal that's coming through the material? Can I narrow the beam of the radio wave towards a certain direction?

Comment: Should be a "difficult" problem. The problem is really the "proximity" and the little area of PLA. Perhaps using directives antennas and some absorbers between Rx2 and Tx? Or by "evaluating" the "contributions of "direct"  and "reflected" radiation based on delay. Or by "difference" when PLA is there or not. Rx1 and Rx2 can also interact with each other. In fine, I should use the property of the dielectric inserted in a coaxial line of known impedance. It should then be easy to consider PLA as a "defect" in this line. (reflective and transmissive coefficient should "easily" be calculated?)

Comment: Something as the "spacer" in this air coax line ... https://www.engineersedge.com/instrumentation/coaxial_cable_connectors_assemblies_review_9894.htm

Comment: Thank you @Antonio51, perhaps what you suggested about directional antennas and the difference between the PLA being there and not being there would be a good starting point